# How can I persist previous fortify scan comment after fortify upgrade

Tags: security, fortify

I did fortify scan with older version and updated my analysis , comment and justification. Then I Upgraded fortify software version and again re scan the application. Is it possible to persist my older comment in new version.

Thank in Advance and appreciated your help.

Regards

Abdul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To persist previous comment , just open the last fpr project from fortify menu in Visual Studio (Fortify -> Open Audit Project) and scan again and save the project.